# Marker component not rendering markers when using .map within a .then

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

I am trying to render markers for some various longitudes and latitudes on my map and for some reason, when the app loads, I dont see any markers on the screen.  I dont even get any errors and dont see any anything when debugging, 
Here is the code for my render method.

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {/* If user location data is allowed and retrieved */}
        {this.state.ready && (
          <MapView
            provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            showsUserLocation
            style={styles.map}
            region={{
              latitude: this.state.coords.lat,
              longitude: this.state.coords.lng,
              latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
              longitudeDelta: 0.0421
            }}
          >
            {this.renderVendorMarkers()}
          </MapView>
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This.state. ready refers to a boolean property I set based on some permissions.

The method which will be rendering the markers is "this.renderVendorMarkers()"
The code for that method is as follows:

```
renderVendorMarkers = () => {
    const { locations } = this.state;
    this.getCoordinates(locations).then(coords => {
      return (
        <View>
          {coords.map((coord, idx) => {
            return (
              <Marker
                key={idx}
                coordinate={{ latitude: coord.lat, longitude: coord.lng }}
              />
            );
          })}
        </View>
      );
    });
  };
```

This method references a locations property which is linked to a json file with user full addresses and another method called getCoordinates which returns an array of promises that correspond to the google.maps api to fetch the address.

```
  getCoordinates = vendors => {
    const APIKEY = "myApiKey";     //Put a fake value here but in code, use a real API key
    const promises = vendors.map(async vendor => {
      const vendorID = vendor.VendorID;
      const fullAddress = `${vendor.VendorAddress},${vendor.VendorCity},${vendor.VendorState}`;
      try {
        const resp = await fetch(
          `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${fullAddress}&key=${APIKEY}`
        );
        const respJson = await resp.json();
        return respJson.results[0].geometry.location;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
  };
```

Basically, I have a json file with a list of user addresses.  I want to drop markers on the map with the user's longitude and latitude.

My getCoordinates method works the way I want it to. It seems that the issue is with the renderVendorMarkers method.  When looping through the list of coordinates(retrieved from the getCoordinates method), the marker isnt rendering.  Please let me know if you want me to clarify further.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: You can't render with async code like `.then` - render code needs to be synchronous. You probably want to call `this.getCoordinates` in a component lifecycle method like `componentDidMount`, then call `setState` with the result. Your `renderVendorMarkers` should then render based on the updated value in `this.state` after the async `getCoordinates` completes and calls `setState`.

Comment: Thank you so much.  That seemed to do the trick.  Im still new to react-native.  This was driving me crazy. I did like you suggested.  Added a call to the getCoordinates in the componentDidMount() where I set the state to the coordinates.  Then called the renderVendorMarker method after the fact within the render method and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this, the answer is as follows:

1. Call the getCoordinates method within the `componentDidMount()`.  Here I set the state.

```js
this.getCoordinates(this.state.locations).then(coords => {
    this.setState({ vendorCoords: coords });
});
```

2. Within the render method of the component, I call the `renderVendorMarkers()`.

```js
{this.renderVendorMarkers()}
```

The renderVendorMarker method itself is:

```
 renderVendorMarkers = () => {
    const { vendorCoords } = this.state;
    if (vendorCoords) {
      return (
        <View>
          {vendorCoords.map((vendorCoord, idx) => {
            return (
              <Marker
                key={idx}
                coordinate={{
                  latitude: vendorCoord.lat,
                  longitude: vendorCoord.lng
                }}
              />
            );
          })}
        </View>
      );
    }
  };
```